# How to change coding language in code stage of blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I have problem in blueprism

how to change coding language in code stage (from VB.net to C#) of blueprism. I getting error while writing code in C#.

Answer (score 3):

You go to Initialize Page and open business object properties (click on that thing that says "Created by" etc) - Code options tab - at the botton there is a language selection.
[image]

Comment: Please provide detailed explanation.not able find Initialize stage

Comment: see screenshot :)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Initialise page and change the code from VB to C#.

[image: Go to Initialise page and change the code from VB to C#]